# Setting a button's position to random points on screen? - Android

Tags: android, button, random, position

Below, I've got both the Java and XML code, basically I'm trying to click a fixed button, and make the 2nd button jump around the screen at random points

**XML Explanation:**
So, I've got a relative layout with two buttons... One of them is fixed at the bottom of the screen... and I want to set the other one's position randomly.

Screen opens, Click the fixed button... and the other button's position should change randomly.

Say I click the fixed button again and agin, the other button should jump around randomly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Rrand" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rbb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bss"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="aa"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA Explanation**
And here I've got the OnClick function for the fixed button.

►b = The button that's supposed to jump around

First of all, we get the screen dimensions, and then using LayoutParams, set the buttons position using the random function.

```
   public void Clicky(View v) {
            b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rbb1);

    ///Getting the Screen dimensions for API 1+

            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    ///Setting the buttons paramaters, again for API 1+

            params.leftMargin = b.getWidth()
                    + new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - b.getWidth());
            params.topMargin = b.getHeight()
                    + new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - b.getHeight());
            b.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
```

**Random Function** for the X coordinate:

b.getWidth()+ new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - b.getWidth());

Minimum value = b.getWidth().

So, IN THEORY, the button should never ever even partially appear a little out the screen.

In the parameters for nextInt, I use [Screenwidth - Button Width] ... So, IN THEORY, it should never go out of the screen from the other side too...

**Problem**
Yet it does. Approximately half the time, the button does not even appear on the screen... The problem has to be in the Random Function (I think so) ... I just want it to appear on random spots on the screen.

I reckon the problem is simply logical, because I have all the functions I need..

**This didn't work**
►Setting a Margin on the button and the Relative Layour.
►Removing all button dimension parameter from the random function.

That is, using:

new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels)

So, what did I get wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you add `b.getWidth()` to the random value, you have to change the random value to `metrics.widthPixels - 2*b.getWidth()`, because otherwize the offset could be `metrics.widthPixels - b.getWidth() + b.getWidth` which explains why it is out of border to the right and to the bottom sometimes. So it should look like this:

```
params.leftMargin = b.getWidth()
                + new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - 2*b.getWidth());
params.topMargin = b.getHeight()
                + new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - 3*b.getHeight());
b.setLayoutParams(params);
```

NOTE: In this version, the button will never touch the left edge or top edge of the screen.

---

If you want to the button also to (possibly) touch the upper and/or left border, don't add width/height to margin:

```
params.leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - b.getWidth());
params.topMargin = new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - 2*b.getHeight());
b.setLayoutParams(params);
```

---

Edit:
I changed the calculation of the top margin so the button woun't be at the same position as the fixed button.

Comment: Nope ! ... Still doesn't work .. (Although, It does appear inside the screen approx 80% of the time...)

Comment: What about if you remove padding from `RelativeLayout` in XML file?

Comment: Nevermind ! I got it to work.... Juggled around with how much I'm subtracting inside the Random()... and how much I'm adding outside.. :-) ... And yes, it turns out, the padding was causing it to be invisible whenever it collided :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
public class OpenArea extends Activity {

    private RelativeLayout loOPenArea;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open);

        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        loOPenArea = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lo_open_area);
    }

    public void addView(View v) {
        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        loOPenArea.addView(imageView);

        int leftMargin = new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - imageView.getWidth());;
        int topMargin = new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - 2*imageView.getHeight());;

        setMargins(imageView, leftMargin, topMargin, 0, 0);
    }

    private void setMargins(View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
            view.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lo_open_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:onClick="addView"
        android:text="+" />
</LinearLayout>
```